# Save current VF PDF page in document

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, renderas

I build a VF page render as PDF. This page contains Case field and image from other service. Now I want to save the PDF after the page is fully render in one document folder "Crash PDF" and than update one field in the Case object with the id of the document created.

My VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="CrashDossierPDFController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" action="{!loadData}">
[....]
<apex:page>
```

Whit loadData fuction I query all the required field.

Is it possible whitin the same context? How can I do that?

I tried whit a wrapper page like that:

```
<apex:page action="{!savePDF}" controller="CrashDossierWrapperExtension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <!-- Here comes another page with a content to be converted to PDF -->
    <apex:include pageName="CrashDossierPDF"/>
</apex:page>
```

Where savePDF is:

```
public PageReference savePDF(){
        System.debug('savePDF CrashDossierWrapperExtension');
        Case currentCase = [SELECT Id, OCTO_ID_Crash_OTP__c, OCTO_IMEI__c,OCTO_Crash_Map_Image_Id__c,OCTO_Crash_Dossier_PDF_Id__c
                         FROM Case WHERE Id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        System.debug('case: '+currentCase);
        Folder folder = [SELECT Id FROM Folder WHERE Name = 'CrashDossierPDF'];
        System.debug('folder: '+ folder);
if(currentCase.OCTO_Crash_Dossier_PDF_Id__c ==null || currentCase.OCTO_Crash_Dossier_PDF_Id__c ==''){ 
            PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/CrashDossierPDF?id='+currentCase.id);
            Document pdfDoc = new Document();
            pdfDoc.FolderId = folder.Id;
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                pdfDoc.Body = pdf.getContent();
            }
            pdfDoc.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
            pdfDoc.Name = 'CrashDossier.pdf';
            insert pdfDoc;
            System.debug('**PDF ** '+ pdfDoc);
            //case update
            currentCase.OCTO_Crash_Dossier_PDF_Id__c = pdfDoc.Id;
            update currentCase;
            System.debug('**Case ** '+ currentCase);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

PDF is actually saved but lost its style and page format.

Comment: Did you try that already? Is that working ?

Comment: @L.benedettini, should be possible.

Comment: I tried using a wrapper page and apex:include like that: <apex:page action="{!savePDF}" controller="CrashDossierWrapperExtension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <!-- Here comes another page with a content to be converted to PDF -->
    <apex:include pageName="CrashDossierPDF"/>
</apex:page>. But the problem is the PDF page lost its format and style in this way

Comment: Why are you using `apex:include`?

Comment: i use apex:include to render the VF page as PDF and the parent page to save it whit the method savePDF

Comment: If anyone need, I did it but instead of using an apex:include, i used an iframe all seems works perfectly, thanks for helping me